# Change ISO volume label on OS X?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, filesystem

I have some ISO files here with weird volume labels. I want to rename them to something I can easily remember.

I know in Windows using either winiso or poweriso (both are non-free?) it can be done but I'm not so sure in OS X. I did search the net but nothing useful came up.

Thanks!

edit: I believe it's best explained with an example:

I have an ISO file called "myiso.iso". When I double-click on the ISO file to mount it, it appears as "myweirdname" in Finder."myweirdname" is the ISO Volume name.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way, that I know of, natively in OS X to edit the *volume label/name* of an ISO Image as can be done by using, e.g., UltraISO in Windows.  In other words, with the proper preferences set for UltraISO the *volume label/name* can be changed and saved to the ISO Image without recompiling it. I actually use UltraISO under OS X via Wine for this very reason.

Although this cannot be done natively directly under OS X, nonetheless it can be done using `hdiutil` by creating a new ISO Image from the mounted ISO Image having the *volume label/name* wanting to be changed.

You'll need to use the `hdiutil imageinfo` command, e.g. `hdiutil imageinfo $NAME.ISO`, to get the necessary information to configure the `hdiutil makehybrid` command to make the new ISO Image having the *volume label/name* that your want, instead of what it currently is. Have a look at the man page for [`hdiutil`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html) or just type `hdiutil makehybrid -help` in Terminal.

As an example, I'm going to use an ISO Image, of a DVD, that does not contain any [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management), as the source has to be DRM free.

The key info I'm looking at is, `partition-scheme:`, `partition-name:` and `partition-filesystems:` showing respectively, `ISO9660`, `$NAME`, and both `ISO9660: $NAME` and `UDF: $NAME` where `$NAME` is shown as, e.g., `FOO_BAR_WEIRD` in all three places.

I just want it to say `FOO_BAR`, getting rid of the `WEIRD` part, so my command line will be as follows, after first mounting the `FOO_BAR_WEIRD.ISO` image by double-clicking it in Finder, in Terminal I used the following command:

```
hdiutil makehybrid -iso -udf -iso-volume-name FOO_BAR -udf-volume-name FOO_BAR -o FOO_BAR.ISO /Volumes/FOO_BAR_WEIRD
```

I then used `hdiutil imageinfo FOO_BAR.ISO` and compared it to the output of `hdiutil imageinfo FOO_BAR_WEIRD.ISO` and it showed it has the same `partition-scheme:` and `partition-filesystems:` but different `$NAME`, as it should. The file size was ~.5MB larger however the newly created ISO Image had the name I wanted and played just fine as the original did.

So, it's doable but it takes a little time, work and extra disk space, which is why I run UltraISO via Wine under OS X. :)

Note: I tested this using a DRM free ISO Image of a Movie DVD and may require additional command line options and or additional steps depending on the type and contents of the ISO image.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue myself.  Even though you change the name of the ISO, when mounted it gives these arbitrary names as the mount point.  After much trial & error, reading upon reading, and learning more about CD/DVD directory allocation than I ever wanted to know, I have stumbled upon a process that is quite simple and achieves the desired results.

Note: I assume you already have created an ISO image via whatever software application you use.

I am working in the downloads folder of my Mac...

1) Create a new folder with the desired mount point name, will be used later as the new mount name.  It is character limited (I believe less that 16 characters) and does not like spaces.  If you need to separate words use the *underscore*.

2) mount the offending iso.

3) select the iso in finder ctrl+a to select all items in the image.

4) ctrl+v to paste contents into the newly created folder.

5) Once the content has completed the copy, open the diskutility gui.

6) Select File > New Image > Image from Folder.

7) Select the New folder you created with the desired mount name.

8) Direct the new image to be created in your documents directory (I have found fewer errors in the process when sending it to a directory other that the active one containing the image files), select unencrypted option, select DVD/Master as format.

9) this will create a new image in the documents folder as a .cdr with the name of whatever you elected in the previous screen.  rename the .cdr to .iso as these are basically the same.

10) mount the newly created .iso and the mount name should now be whatever the folder name was that you created the image from.....   tada!

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 1):

I created a python script to resolve this exact issue. I saw [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/361479) that talks about the offsets that these disk images use. I wasn't able to find a specification, but through some quick research with Hex Fiend I was able to spot them all. It turns out that there are just such offsets for UDF iso images, too. I haven't tested this extensively, but it works on the two images I could find on my system.

The offsets I discovered are: 
32808, 65561, 67701, 71765, 98329, 100469 and 104533

You'll need to use terminal and I believe that Python 2 is stock with macOS, so this should work for you.

`./update-names.py myiso.iso`

It writes irreversibly to your file, so make sure that you have a backup.

Here is the code if you'd like to try it yourself. It's python version 2 (my apologies): 
https://gist.github.com/ranvel/bc1d75cc7f9fd74e92630092f4fcda8b